# show div on hover css only not working

Tags: css, html, hover

Hello i have tried everything, but still does not work, i have problems showing div2 on hover over div1.

```
<div id="div1">....</div>
<div id="div2" class="hidden"> ...</div>
```

and css:

```
.hidden{block:none;}

#div1:hover + #div2{
   display:block;
}
```

And for some reason div2 does not show on hover?

Answer (score 2):

this is the CSS that you need

```
.hidden{
    display: none;
}

#div1:hover + #div2 {
    display: block;
}
```

your CSS

```
.hidden{block:none;}
```

is incorrect, change "block" to "display"

Comment: typo here u have the exact code that i have #nadole{
 display: none;
}
#art1:hover #nadole{
       display: block;

} where <div id="art1">...</div><div id="nadole">...</div>

Comment: well, based on your comment, you should have #art1:hover + #nadole{ display: block; } **see** the "+" between "#art1:hover" and "#nadole"